# Memory allocation and deallocation in Renderscript

Tags: renderscript

It is clear that allocating memory in renderscript can be done using the allocation class. I am unclear as to how this memory will be deallocated or freed.

For example if I wanted to create an array of 10 elements and do so using the allocation class. The Android documentation suggests that it's as simple as using malloc in C.

If anyone could help me understand how the freeing of memory takes place in renderscript I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Same way as other java objects, when the reference to the Allocation object is not reachable as determined by garbage collector then when GC happens it may free the Allocation object and invoke the native-side destructors to free the memory.

Also, user can call Allocation.destroy() to free it manually: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/Allocation.html#destroy()

Comment: On the doc is says **destroy() implies setSurface(null)**. So would this apply if I used Allocation to create an integer or float memory and then use destroy() to release it?

Comment: setSurface is for when you are sharing memory with a camera or a UI view surface. It means it will decrement the reference to the held surface object when destroying the Allocation object. The type of the Allocation is kind of orthogonal to this. If you are creating memory without USAGE_IO then yes just call destroy and it will release the memory. Since an Allocation with USAGE_IO does not own the backing memory, it may be just sharing it, it has to just release it's reference to it.